# MODX: как узнать номер TVs в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, modx

Вот в запросе [[!pdoPage? есть строка:

```
&includeTVs=`BasicDate,city,time,about,status,basic,more....
```

В базе данных нашел таблицу modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues, которая содержит все эти данные.
Получается, что в столбце tmplvarid находится номер, выяснил экспериментально:

```
13 - это BasicDate
17 - city
23 - time
25 - about
и т.д.
```

Где посмотреть, какие номера присвоены другим значениям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ - в админ-панели (вкладка **Элементы** -> **Дополнительные поля** (TV)).
ID указаны в скобках

[image: modx tv]

Программно:

```
if ($idTV = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVar', array('name' => 'adress_company'))){
   echo $idTV->get('id');
}
```

> В базе данных нашел таблицу modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues, которая
> содержит все эти данные

Вы не там ищите. Таблица с дополнительными полями называется **modx_site_tmplvars**

Comment: Zarurson, спасибо огромное! Всё нашёл. Даже больше, чем хотел изначально!

Answer (score 0):

> Где посмотреть...

Там же в таблице..

Ну а если программно, то можно выбрать из `modTemplateVar` по имени, например таким образом:

```
$getTV = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVar', array('name'=> 'basic'));
if($getTV){
   return $getTV->get('id');
}
```

на выходе получим `id` tv-парметра с именем `basic`

Comment: "Там же в таблице.." Нет там никаких строк с названиями